# spplot() - make color.key look nice

Tags: r, graphics, lattice

I'm afraid I have a spplot() question again.

I want the colors in my spplot() to represent absolute values, not automatic values as spplot does it by default.

I achieve this by making a factor out of the variable I want to draw (using the command cut()). This works very fine, but the color-key doesn't look good at all.

See it yourself:

```
library(sp)

data(meuse.grid)
gridded(meuse.grid) = ~x+y

meuse.grid$random <- rnorm(nrow(meuse.grid), 7, 2)
meuse.grid$random[meuse.grid$random < 0] <- 0
meuse.grid$random[meuse.grid$random > 10] <- 10
# making a factor out of meuse.grid$ random to have absolute values plotted
meuse.grid$random <- cut(meuse.grid$random, seq(0, 10, 0.1)) 

spplot(meuse.grid, c("random"), col.regions = rainbow(100, start = 4/6, end = 1))
```

How can I have the color.key on the right look good - I'd like to have fewer ticks and fewer labels (maybe just one label on each extreme of the color.key)

Thank you in advance!

**[edit]**
To make clear what I mean with absolute values: Imagine a map where I want to display the sea height. Seaheight = 0 (which is the min-value) should always be displayed blue. Seaheight = 10 (which, just for the sake of the example, is the max-value) should always be displayed red. Even if there is no sea on the regions displayed on the map, this shouldn't change.
I achieve this with the cut() command in my example. So this part works fine.

**THIS IS WHAT MY QUESTION IS ABOUT**
What I don't like is the color description on the right side. There are 100 ticks and each tick has a label. I want fewer ticks and fewer labels.

Comment: I've never used spplot, but [RColorBrewer](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RColorBrewer/index.html) seems like it may be useful here. I'd add a `library(sp)` at the top of your code there so people can copy/paste/run directly.

Comment: what do you mean by absolute values? do you just want to round the random values to integers?

Comment: thank you Chase! added library(sp)! I thought RColorBrewer is just for selecting colors!! I will have a look at it!

Comment: now had a look at RColorBrewer. It basically does what I did with my rainbow() command. Therefore it seems not to solve my problem...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to go is using the attribute colorkey. For example:

```
## labels
labelat = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
labeltext = c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five")

## plot
spplot(meuse.grid,
    c("random"),
    col.regions = rainbow(100, start = 4/6, end = 1),
    colorkey = list(
        labels=list(
            at = labelat,
            labels = labeltext
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it's not at all clear what you are wanting here. There are many ways to make the `color.key` look "nice" and that is to understand first the data being passed to spplot and what is being asked of it. cut() is providing fully formatted intervals like (2.3, 5.34] which will need to be handled a different way, increasing the margins in the plot, specific formatting and spacing for the labels, etc. etc. This just may not be what you ultimately want.

Perhaps you just want integer values, rounded from the input values?

```
library(sp)

data(meuse.grid)
gridded(meuse.grid) = ~x+y

meuse.grid$random <- rnorm(nrow(meuse.grid), 7, 2)
```

Round the values (or trunc(), ceil(), floor() them . . .)

```
meuse.grid$rclass <- round(meuse.grid$random)

spplot(meuse.grid, c("rclass"), col.regions = rainbow(100, start = 4/6, end = 1))
```

Comment: No, I want to display answers to a questionaire in different regions. The possible answers to the questionaire are 0, 1, 2, ..., 10. Taking the mean of each question in every region gets me decimal values (although this is not very good statistics, as the answers were discrete). Let's say the min-value is 5.5 and the max-value is 8.5. I don't want my map to display 5.5 as blue and 8.5 as red. I want 0 (if existent) displayed as blue and 10 (if existent) displayed as red. That's what I mean with absolute values. BUT I don't want all values displayed as ticks in the color.key.

Comment: does this mean that anything with a value greater than 0 and less than 10 should not display? put this into the question to save people having to search the comments for crucial information

Comment: no! that means anything smaller than 0 and greater than 10 should not be displayed. In fact everything but the label on the right should be just like in my example. I don't want that many ticks and that many captions in the label on the right. everything else should be the same. I will point that out in my question